# Declaring data types

Tags: haskell

I have a data type which I am using to represent rows of columns and columns of rows:

```
data Object a = Row a
                |Column a

data Row a = Object a
             | Left(Row a)(Row a)

data Column a = Object a
             | Above(Column a)(Column a)


testfunction::Object a->String
testfunction Row(Left(c)(d)) = "Recognized row"
```

I would like to know how I can state that a constructor in the Object data type definition may "contain" any constructors which are defined elsewhere and a different constructor in the Object data type definition may "contain" a different set of constructors.

So:

```
data Object a = Object1(Set1 a)
                | Object2(Set2 a)

data Set1 a = A a| B a| C a| D a
data Set2 a = X a| Y a| Z a
```

So the only valid combinations are Object1(A a) Object1(B a) Object1(C a) Object1(D a), Object2(X a), Object2(Y a) and Object2(Z a)

Comment: Note that you should be parenthesising from the outside: the purpose is to group the expressions, not to call functions. i.e. `testfunction (Row (Left c d))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Object a` type works for *all* types `a`. So if you have a value of `Object a` (as you do in your function), you know *nothing* about what `a` is--particularly, you do *not* know that it is a value of type `Row a`!

Now, this is a little confusing because you have specified `Row` twice--as a type and as a constructor of the type `Object`. These two are not related at all. That is, in

```
data Object a = Row a
```

there is nothing forcing `Row a` to contain a value of type `Row`.

The simplest fix--and probably what you actually meant to write--is this:

```
data Object a = Row (Row a)
              | Column (Column a)
```

this is a little confusing because you see `Row` and `Column` twice, but they mean different things each time. It would be clearer if you wrote it as something like:

```
data Object a = ObjRow (Row a)
              | ObjColumn (Column a)
```

(These particular names aren't very good because I couldn't think of what to call them, but hopefully they make the distinction clear.)

After you define `Object` like this, you should be able to pattern match the way you want to.

Comment: So does this mean if I had 8 objects at the "Object" level and they could all contain eachother (like a "Row" contains a "Column" and a "Column" can contain a "Row") there is no easy way to be able to say all 8 objects can contain the cartesian product of eachother, other than to make 64 constructors? In other words, if Object1 can contain Object 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and Object 2 can contain Object 1,3,4,5,6,7,8 there is no easier way to declare this other than writing out the 64  possibilities in the one constructor?

Comment: Edit to my above comment, what if I only wanted to simulate a recursive containment between a subset of Objects 1-8. What I would like to ideally do is group Objects 1-5 into their own definition and then from my statement above, to be able to allow objects 1-8 to contain objects 1-5?